# Parallel file processing with two tasks using the foreach package in R

Tags: r, foreach, parallel.foreach

I have 300 files of 500 MB each. I want to read them in parallel and filter them down based on some arguments.

To replicate the problem, let's assume I have 3 monthly files:

```
library(data.table)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

set.seed(1)
FirstStatus <- data.frame(IDs = sample(1:200, 100, replace = F))

month_1 <- data.table(IDs = sample(1:200, 100, replace = F),
                Month = rep(1, 100),
                Status = rep(c('a','b','c','d'), 25))

month_2 <- data.table(IDs = sample(1:200, 100, replace = F),
                  Month = rep(2, 100),
                  Status = rep(c('a','b','c','d'), 25))

month_3 <- data.table(IDs = sample(1:200, 100, replace = F),
                  Month = rep(3, 100),
                  Status = rep(c('a','b','c','d'), 25))
```

Where FirstStatus is the full ID population. I used the below function to store data into one dataframe.

```
Execute <- function(FirstStatus, Start = 1, End = 3){

   for(i in Start:End){

      print(paste0('Read month ', i )) # Which is in our case month_1 month_2 month_3
      month <- fread(paste0('month_', i ,'.txt')) # monthly files generated above   
      month <- month[IDs %in% FirstStatus$IDs, .(IDs, Month, Status)]
      month <- month[Status %in% c('a','c','d')]

      if(i == Start){
         FirstMonth <- month
      } else {
         FirstMonth <- rbind(FirstMonth, month)
      }

      FirstStatus <- FirstStatus[!(IDs %in% FirstMonth$IDs)]
    }
    return(list('FirstStatus' = FirstStatus, 'FirstMonth' = FirstMonth))
 }

 res <- Execute(FirstStatus = FirstStatus, Start = 1, End = 3)
```

This works fine but it would take time when looping over 300 files. I'm trying to optimize this for-loop by using the foreach package in R but I'm struggling a bit. First I tried to read the first file to extract the 'FirstMonth' and to filter down the 'FirstStatus'

```
cl <- makeCluster(3)
registerDoParallel(cl)
month <- fread(paste0('month_', 1 ,'.txt'))
month <- month[IDs %in% FirstStatus$IDs, .(IDs, Month, Status)]
month <- month[Status %in% c('a','c','d')]
FirstMonth <- month
FirstStatus <- FirstStatus[!(IDs %in% FirstMonth$IDs)]
```

Next, I used foreach to read them in parallel although I'm struggling with updating FirstStatus, and FirstMonth.

```
ExecutePar <- function(FirstStatus, FirstMonth, Start = 2, End = 3){

     foreach(i = 2:3, .combine = 'rbind', .packages = c('data.table','foreach'), .export('FirstStatus','FirstMonth')) %dopar% {

         month <- fread(paste0('month_', i '.txt'))
         month <- month[IDs %in% FirstStatus$IDs, .(IDs, Month, Status)]
         month <- month[Status %in% c('a','c','d')]


         FirstStatus <- FirstStatus[!(IDs %in% c(FirstMonth, Month)$IDs)]
         c(FirstMonth, month)

     }

  }

res <- ExecutePar(FirstStatus, FirstMonth, Start = 2, End = 3)
```

Any advice on how to improve the for-loop is appreciated.

Comment: did you try adding `.export = c("FirstStatus", "FirstMonth")` to the `foreach` arguments?

Comment: Yes, I did and I changed the work environment by using clusterEvalQ(cl = cl, setwd('')). I do get a list of 12 elements while I'm expecting a data frame.